# AutoIT get child window from a parent window

Tags: autoit

I came across a problem which looks trivial to me but I can't find a valid solution after googling for an hour.

I want to fill in a window security popup window.

[image: popup]

This is part of a selenium test, that can run in parallel next to other tests.
So in order to be sure that my autoit script fills in the correct popup (and not form another test that is running), i want to identify this popup as a child of a parent window. Is there an easy way to do this?

The code i had so far:

```
$browserHandl = WinWait($parentTitle)
WinActivate($browserHandl, "")

$popUpHandl = WinWait("Windows Security")
```

So my fear is that WinWait will return one of all the open Windows Security popups currently open on the machine.

So:
1. Is there a way to obtain the childwindows of a parent window when i got its handle?
2. Is my fear correct that i indeed will have a race condition with multiple tests running at the same time?

Comment: EnumChildWindows api (_WinAPI_EnumChildWindows in autoit, helpfile has an example).  However, I doubt that there is ever at one time more than one active (or visible for that matter) windows security window.  Maybe you can look at WinWaitActive.

Comment: Actually it is quite common for multiple security windows to be opened. I will look into this api. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[input box open](http://78ez.com/images/b1jpg.jpg)

[input box hidden](http://78ez.com/images/b2jpg.jpg)

I used a progress to hide what I needed to.
add #include 
$file = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 10, 5, 350, 25)
You need 3 lines for the Marquee
 Local $iProgress = GUICtrlCreateProgress(30, 10, 270, 20, $PBS_MARQUEE)
  GUICtrlSendMsg($iProgress, $PBM_SETMARQUEE, 1, 50)
and to make it cover the input box

and 0 to stop and remove the Marquee GUICtrlSendMsg($iProgress, $PBM_SETMARQUEE, 0, 50) ; Send the message $PBM_SETMARQUEE and wParam of 0 to stop the scrolling marquee.